# Windows error report: Fault buckets

Tags: windows, crash-reports, windows-error-reporting

`Windows error report (WER)` is a tool that identifies a "unique" crash by applying some heuristics and assigning a unique ID to the crash which is known as `fault bucket`. In other words, a fault bucket identification number is a number assigned by the system to identify specific types of errors, usually based on a specific application.

Is there a way by which we can determine how many times a particular crash ID is generated i.e. does Microsoft provide a mechanism to fetch an application related error info so that we can get an idea as what percentage of users get a particular crash?

Comment: You access crash info from your Windows Dev Center dash board.  Probably something you haven't setup yet when you ask a question like this, [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/br230782).

Comment: @HansPassant Among the dashboard services in the link provided you, which service will provide the information I require? I was looking into the [Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/br230776.aspx) service, but that too doesn't say anything about the unique fault buckets..